# How to find rectangle's corner coordinate with few given information

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine

[image]

I know the coordinate of red points and center point of rectangle, i also know the width and length of rectangle (2D world).

So how do i find coordinate of X point (bottom left corner)?

Comment: The rectangle in the figure looks axis-aligned. Is it?

Comment: @Nico Schertler No its not.

Comment: Could you use raycast?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about math, not programming.

Comment: Why aren't you combining the `x` coordinate from the point placed on the left side of the rectangle and `y` coordinate from the point on the bottom side of the rectangle? You don't need to calculate anything. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Let me summarize your problem to make sure we are on the same page. You have an arbitrary rectangle with known center, width, and height. And you know two arbitrary points on the left edge and on the bottom edge.

If you had the midpoints of the two edges, the problem would be easy:

```
BottomLeft = CenterBottom + (CenterLeft - Center)
```

So the question is how to calculate these points.

I will explain this for one edge (in this case the bottom edge). The same holds for the left edge. Let's call the center of the rectangle `C`, the midpoint of the edge `M`, and the arbitrary point on the edge `E`.

You can calculate the distance between `C` and `E`. If `E` were the midpoint, this distance would be exactly half the rectangle's height. But it is not. What we can do with this information is calculate the angle `MCE`:

```
cos MCE = h / (2 * |C - E|)
```

So all we have to do to find M is rotate the direction vector by this angle and re-scale:

```
M = C + rotate(E - C, MCE) * h / (2 * |C - E|)
```

There are two solutions for that. One with a positive angle and one with a negative angle.

So just calculate the two possible midpoints for the two edges. If you have these, you need to check which of the four pairs are valid. To do so, simply check if the angle between `C - MLeft` and `C - MBottom` is 90° (i.e. their dot product is close to zero).

Once you have a valid pair, you can calculate the corner as described above. Note that there may be more than one valid solution.